# Saving DataSet<Row> to Ignite

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

Here is my code

```
public static void save(IgniteContext igniteContext, String cacheName, Dataset<Row> dataSet) {
        CacheConfiguration<BinaryObject, BinaryObject> cacheConfiguration = new CacheConfiguration<BinaryObject, BinaryObject>(cacheName)
                .setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.ATOMIC)
                .setBackups(0)
                .setAffinity(new RendezvousAffinityFunction(false, 2))
                .setIndexedTypes(BinaryObject.class, BinaryObject.class);
        IgniteCache<BinaryObject, BinaryObject> rddCache = igniteContext.ignite()
                .getOrCreateCache(cacheConfiguration)
                .withKeepBinary();
        rddCache.clear();
        IgniteRDD<BinaryObject, BinaryObject> igniteRDD = igniteContext.fromCache(cacheName);
        StructField[] fields = dataSet.schema().fields();
        RDD<BinaryObject> binaryObjectJavaRDD = dataSet.toJavaRDD().map(row -> {
            BinaryObjectBuilder valueBuilder = igniteContext.ignite().binary().builder(BinaryObject.class.getCanonicalName());
            for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                valueBuilder.setField(fields[i].name(), convertValue(String.valueOf(row.get(i)), fields[i].dataType())); //convertValue converts value to specific datatype
            }
            return valueBuilder.build();
        }).rdd();
        
        igniteRDD.saveValues(binaryObjectJavaRDD);
}
```

I have a problem with the above code, that  is even after successful completion of this method cache remains empty. `Dataset` has 20 rows so that is not the problem.

The other problem is that if I use `savePairs` method from `IgniteRDD` then I have to generate the `Key` by myself(here Key is `BinaryObject`), so how to do that?

## update

```
saveDFInPairs(IgniteContext igniteContext, Dataset<Row> dataSet, IgniteRDD<BinaryObject, BinaryObject> igniteRDD) {
    StructField[] fields = dataSet.schema().fields();
    JavaRDD<Tuple2<BinaryObject, BinaryObject>> rdd = dataSet.toJavaRDD().map(row -> {
        BinaryObjectBuilder keyBuilder = igniteContext.ignite()
                        .binary().builder("TypeName");
        keyBuilder.setField("id", row.mkString().hashCode());
        BinaryObject key = keyBuilder.build();
        
        BinaryObjectBuilder valueBuilder = igniteContext.ignite()
                       .binary().builder("TypeName");
        for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            valueBuilder.setField(fields[i].name(), convert(row, i, fields[i].dataType())); 
        }
        BinaryObject value = valueBuilder.build();
        return new Tuple2<>(key, value);
    });
        
    igniteRDD.savePairs(rdd.rdd(), true);
}
```

Comment: I am also facing similar issue..how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of considerations:

- The type name (the one passed to the `builder()` method) should be a meaningful name representing the data type. Do not use `BinaryObject` class name for this.
- `setIndexedTypes(BinaryObject.class, BinaryObject.class)` is incorrect. This should specify classes to be processed for query annotations. If you don't have classes, you can use `QueryEntity` to configure queries. See this page for further details: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/sql-queries

Other than that code looks correct. I would recommend to try with default settings and check if it works this way. Also it's not very clear how you check that the data is in cache or not.

Comment: So I just need to know a bit more about my second part of the question. I have updated the code for saving `DataSet<Row>` using `savePairs` method of `IgniteRdd`. Here you can see I am using hash of values to generate key which I don't feel is the right way to do it. Can you please add some light on generating  `BinaryObject` as `Key`.

Comment: You should define your key-value data model. Typically there is ID field (or something similar) in each row that can be used as a key. Note that you actually don't have `BinaryObject`. If there is only one field (string, long, etc.), just use it as-is.